# Bulk status update on dropdown list change

Tags: jquery, yii, cgridview

I have drop down list for bulk status upload

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('updateStatus',
                'updateStatus',
                Lookup::items('NodeStatus'),
                array(
                      'prompt' => '',
                      'ajax'=>array(
                                    'type'=>'POST',
                                    'url' => CController::createUrl('node/bulkStatus'),
                                    'data'=> array('updateStatus' => 'js:this.value', 'autoId' => 'js:$("input[name=autoId]:checked").map(function () {return this.value;}).get().join(",")'), 
                                    'success'=>'reloadGrid',
                                    'update'=>'#msg', //selector to update
                                    ),
                                )                          
                );
?>
```

I am struggling to get the value of all checked value of input checkbox in above ajax option which are like this:

```
<input id="autoId_6" type="checkbox" name="autoId[]" value="11">
<input id="autoId_5" type="checkbox" name="autoId[]" value="10">
<input id="autoId_8" type="checkbox" name="autoId[]" value="6">
```

I have looked into post in firebug , autoId is empty and updateStatus is working fine. I want to send autoId values as an array to the action where I can loop through array:

```
public function actionBulkStatus()
{ 
    if(isset($_POST['updateStatus']))
    {
        $autoIdAll = $_POST['autoId'];
        if(count($autoIdAll)>0)
        {
            foreach($autoIdAll as $autoId)
            {
                $model=$this->loadModel($autoId);
                $model->Status = $_POST['updateStatus'];
                $model->save();
            }
        }
        echo "successfully update";
    }
}
```

How can I pass the autoId checked value as an array in ajax data option of dropDownList?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. 
Remove `.join(",")` from `.get().join(..)` and checkboxes names should be just `autoId`, remove `[]` and you should do fine.